# How to redirect from one specific page only

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect

As a Google Trusted street view photographer, our company is listed in Google with our website. See it here:
[Photo of our Google listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKQx6.jpg)

The thing is, we are only allowed to give the homepage link, like www.aemotion.com. But what I want is when visitors click the link on that page only, they will be redirected to this page: http://www.aemotion.com/google-street-view-van-mooi-van/.

I know a normal htaccess redirect will redirect all trafic from the homepage and that's not what we want obviously.

Anybody an idea how to tackle this?

Comment: Not fully clear what do you want can you elaborate more, where do user click and from where you want to redirect?

Comment: Open dev tools on your browser, select the network tab then click the link. Does the request contain any information that would identify that you had clicked through from that specific link? If yes, you can check for that info server side and redirect as needed. If not, maybe you can add a subdomain `street-view.aemotion.com` to the google listing, then redirect form there? Failing that, buy another domain specifically for this purpose, they cost next to nothing anyway

Comment: Finally, before you do anything, check googles terms. Even if you can find a way to do what you want, if it breaks googles terms, then you wont be a "Google Trusted..." for long

Comment: @Steve We've thought about buying another domain. It's easy indeed. And thanks for pointing out about Google terms. We don't like it to loose the Trusted badge ;-)

Comment: No problem. If you go with the selected answer, be aware that anyone that finds your company via a google netherlands search result is going to get redirected, not just those that come via the specific listing. This could have serious implications! It could also get you penalized in google search. Tread carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's `$_SERVER` variable, so if the user came from http://www.google.nl (I see that you're from the Netherlands) than redirect to that page.

So your code will be:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://www.google.nl') {
    Header('Location: /google-street-view-van-mooi-van/');
}
```

---

You could also use a specific `get` variable. For example: `http://www.aemotion.com/?reffer=site_name`. After that you can add the follow code:

```
if(isset($_GET['reffer'])) {
    if($_GET['reffer'] == 'site_name') {
        Header('Location: /google-street-view-van-mooi-van/';
    } else if($_GET['reffer'] == 'site_name_2') {
        Header('Location: /google-street-view-van-mooi-van/';
    }
}
```

This works also for multiple sites.

---

Hope this works!

Hopelijk werkt dit! (in Dutch)

Comment: Your welcome! If you have any more question, you could always contact me @ThijsMoens

Answer (score 0):

If they pass you a `$_GET` variable or `$_POST` variable you could check for that and redirect accordingly.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['external_redirect'])) {
    header("Location: /someOther/location");
    exit;
}
```